# FB Pixel: how to ignore test events when optimizing targeted ads?

Tags: facebook, event-tracking, ads, facebook-pixel

I'm new to Facebook pixel and analytics. 
I wanted to install FB Pixel to increase ads performance, and while testing I sent some fake events.

If I understood correctly, when FB optimizes(i.e., increase sign up) ads using Pixel, it does the following:

- Find which users signed up so far
- Analyze demographic of those users
- Inside FB's user pool, find users who have similar demographic with who signed up for our website
- Show targeted ads to them

So I'm now worried about test events. If those events are not ignored and used to optimize targeted ads, it would affect the optimization performance. In other words, it would show ads to wrong targets.

Does my worry reasonable? If so, what is the way to ignore test events? FYI, I asked to facebook ad support team but she din't know the detail, and she said the DB record about test events cannot be deleted.